# React is not defined when bundling

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack

I am new to TypeScript and thought I would tray the product List demo from ReactJS website with it. I have got so far, but currently getting

```
external "React":1 Uncaught ReferenceError: React is not defined
    at Object.react (external "React":1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
    at Object../src/client/app/index.tsx (index.tsx:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
    at bootstrap:83
    at bootstrap:83
```

and I am not too sure why, if I include it as an external in my `webpack.config.js` it works fine, but I am wanting to bundle it with the rest of the src ready for intranet applications that dont have access to the big bad world.

Any help would be appreciated.

I am importing thus `import * as React from 'react';`

webpack throws no errors

INDEX.TSX

```html
import * as React from 'react';
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');

import FilterableProductTable from './components/FilterableProductTable';
import Basket from './components/Basket';

ReactDOM.render(
 <div>
  <FilterableProductTable />
  <Basket />
 </div>,
 document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Comment: Share your webpack configuration. Also, you don't need to use `import * as React`.
Just call `import React from 'react'`

Comment: @LucaFabbri When using TypeScript `import * as React from 'react'` is the correct way.

Comment: I'm dealing with exactly the same problem now. I found this [link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/react-&-webpack.html) that might help you, it said that it's necessary to create a new index.html adding the react dependencies. If I found a better answer I'll let you know

Comment: I made a React project based on the [ts-loader "vanilla" example](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader/tree/master/examples/vanilla) and React got bundled fine, so I don't think there's any universal requirement to use React as an external.  Can you publish a repository of your project that isn't working?

Comment: @MattMcCutchen, do you know if there are any difference if it's used `awesome-typescript-loader` instead of `ts-loader`?

Comment: @octavioccl I don't think there should be a difference.  Publish a repository that reproduces the problem and I will look.

Answer (score 2):

I've been having this issue too. After googling the error for a day or so, I stumbled across this page.

Following the link provided by octavioccl in the comments - (http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/react-&-webpack.html).

I swear I've read this page a dozen or so times, and roughly tried following it while I've been converting my project across to TypeScript. Anyways, what helped me what this section here:

"We’ll also need a page to display our Hello component. Create a file at the root of proj named index.html with the following contents:"

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>Hello React!</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="example"></div>

        <!-- Dependencies -->
        <script src="./node_modules/react/umd/react.development.js"></script>
        <script src="./node_modules/react-dom/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

        <!-- Main -->
        <script src="./dist/bundle.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

"Notice that we’re including files from within node_modules. React and React-DOM’s npm packages include standalone .js files that you can include in a web page, and we’re referencing them directly to get things moving faster. Feel free to copy these files to another directory, or alternatively, host them on a content delivery network (CDN). Facebook makes CDN-hosted versions of React available..."

I added the Dependancies to my index.html file and it sorted this issue.

Hopefully that helps someone else who stumbles across this.